# Cannot use one of my element declared in my own library

Tags: html, angular, npm, angular-library

I am trying to make a library that I can use a component from but angular says that the element I use is not recognized as an element. I am trying to export the VitalSignLinesListComponent.

The steps I follow are:

1. declare the component in the library module
2. export the component
   in the library module
3. export the component in the public API
4. import the module from the library
5. place the element in the html
   file
6. receive error

The error I am getting:

> ERROR in src/app/app.component.html:2:1 - error NG8001:
>   'lib-vital-sign-lines-list' is not a known element: 1. If
>   'lib-vital-sign-lines-list' is an Angular component, then verify that
>   it is part of this module. 
>           2. If 'lib-vital-sign-lines-list' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component
>   to suppress this message.

COMPONENT:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'lib-vital-sign-lines-list',
  templateUrl: './vital-sign-lines-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./vital-sign-lines-list.component.css']
})

export class VitalSignLinesListComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input()
  idEdDossier: string;
}
```

LIBRARY MODULE:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { VitalsignsComponent } from './vitalsigns.component';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { ModalInputComponent } from './modal-input/modal-input.component';
import { VitalSignLinesListComponent } from './vital-sign-lines-list/vital-sign-lines-list.component';
import { NgSelectModule } from '@ng-select/ng-select';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { EcareLibModule } from 'ecarelib'
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { ComboBoxComponent } from './combo-box/combo-box.component';
import { ComboBoxPipe } from './combo-box/combo-box.pipe';
import { LogService } from './services/log.service';
import { ClickOutsideDirective } from './vital-sign-lines-list/click-outside.directive';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'modal', component: ModalInputComponent },
  { path: 'vitalSignLinesList', component: VitalSignLinesListComponent }
];

// @dynamic
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    VitalsignsComponent,
    ModalInputComponent,
    VitalSignLinesListComponent,
    ComboBoxComponent,
    ComboBoxPipe,
    ClickOutsideDirective
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    EcareLibModule.forRoot(),
    NgSelectModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, { enableTracing: false }),
    FormsModule,
    NgbModule
  ],
  providers: [LogService],
  exports: [VitalsignsComponent, VitalSignLinesListComponent]
})
export class VitalsignsModule {

}
```

PUBLIC-API:

```
export * from './lib/vitalsigns.service';
export * from './lib/vitalsigns.component';
export * from './lib/vitalsigns.module';
export * from './lib/vital-sign-lines-list/vital-sign-lines-list.component';
```

IMPORT LIBRARY: (VitalsignsModule)

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { NgSelectModule } from '@ng-select/ng-select';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { EcareLibModule } from 'ecarelib';
import { VitalsignsModule } from 'vitalsigns';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    EcareLibModule.forRoot(),
    HttpClientModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([]),
    VitalsignsModule,
    NgbModule,
    NgSelectModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

HTML:

```
<lib-vital-sign-lines-list [idEdDossier]=idDossier></lib-vital-sign-lines-list>
```

Comment: Sometimes, just restarting the app can resolve such issues :P. You can try once.

Comment: i have done that a lot already